# Cannot install nuget source package from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, azure-mobile-services

I need to install the source package of a mobileservice package: following the instructions at

http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables

I try to install it using the command

```
Install-Package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables -Version 1.0.348 -Source http://nuget.gw.symbolsource.org/Public/NuGet/FeedService.mvc
```

but I receive the error message that the **package cannot be found**. If I try to browse the  Feed url the response is an empty collection.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it to debug inside VS? If so then you don't have to install the package manually. Rather, you can just follow the instructions here [1] to get the source & symbols loaded in the VS debugger.

Henrik

[1] http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/03/14/debugging-net-backend-in-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Hi, this is the stack trace  
> at  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Serialization.SelectExpandWrapperConverter‌​.get_DictionaryConvertibleType()\r\n at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Tables.TableQueryFilter.AddETagResponseHea‌​der(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Tables.TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecuted(H‌​ttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n 
 
I don't know how to fine the problem without debugging the source directly, so I'm trying to run from the sources.